# РОССИЯ И/ИЛИ В РОССИИ ТЕРРОРИСТИЧЕСКИЙ РЕЖИМ?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Парламентская ассамблея Совета Европы одобрила резолюцию под названием
> "Дальнейшая эскалация агрессии Российской Федерации против Украины", в
> которой Российская Федерация названа "террористическим режимом". Об
> этом сообщают члены делегации Украины в ПАСЕ.
> https://www.svoboda.org/a/pase-v-rezolyutsii-nazvala-rf-terroristicheskim-rezhimom-/32080798.html

Как РФ может быть режимом? Это в РФ может быть определённый режим.
Т.е. некорректно написано в статье?

Comment: Может, имеется в виду, что Россию государством назвать нельзя (т.к. для этого должны быть соблюдены определённые критерии), а только режимом и можно?